# GitHub unable to pull from npm repo

Tags: angular, github, npm

I have been trying for about 2 hours to get a repo: https://github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components#ecl-3d-components to load into my angular project with no luck.

- I have had it working before and have been trying this command `npm i cmelange/ECL-3D-Components#v1.0`.
- I have also tried pinging the github server from my powershell and it is reponding, it just can't find the page.
- My work's support department is telling me the firewall is not the issue, but I have no idea what else it could be...

```
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tassc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-04T12_35_00_266Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\tassc\Projects\PatioCoveringModels> npm i
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 140.82.118.4]: errno=No such file or directory
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR!     C:\Users\tassc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-04T12_56_46_865Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Just because something is on git, doesn't mean it is accessible through npm. Are you sure that this package is in npm? I can't find it on their website...? https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cmelange

Comment: 100% guaranteed its an npm package on github. I have it before on a different project. It is written by my boss specifically to be npm compatible.

Comment: but it is not hosted on an official npm. I have no idea why.

Comment: Has you boss / company hosted it on a private / on-prem npm registry? which would mean you would have to change your npm config to point to that instead.

Comment: The npm source is uploaded to github. which is a publicly accessible repository as I am currently looking at it. (Clicking the github link in my post will bring you to the repo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a firewall issue. I too face this issue frequently. The below approach works for me.
Try these below commands and force npm to use http:// instead of git://.

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm -rf bower_components`

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

`git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`

Let us know if it works for you as well.

Comment: I should probably mention I am in VSCode on Windows. Because the first command is already throwing errors...

Comment: You can open a bash terminal in vscode  or you can use git bash. The first two commands are to delete those folder, you can even right click and delete them.

Comment: fair enough, I deleted them myself but unfortunately that did not resolve my problem. Running those followed by an npm install resulted in the same issue... I should note I am not in control of the firewall as it is managed over the network. I have asked out support team to take a look...

Comment: do you have git installed. If yes then please right click in your repository and then execute the third command <git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://>. After that please do npm install. This line is really important.

Comment: Appearantly the firewall was indeed the issue. I just got back to work, and asked why it didnt work. I was told git requests are not allowed in the same way https is... Nowit works...

Comment: In my case, the following command worked for me.

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`